# Accessing data within a view passed from model - Aurelia

Tags: json, aurelia

Yes another Aurelia question, apologies!

So I'm trying to access data within my view passed from a model, whilst I can see the data within the `response`, I cannot seem to get it to display on the view. Any help greatly appreciated.

I've tried a few things but I guess being new to Aurelia,ES6 and promises, it's throwing me out a little or I've been staring at to long.

//EDIT Data Access Component

```
import {inject} from "aurelia-framework";
import {HttpClient} from "aurelia-http-client";

let baseUrl = "/FormDesigner";

@inject(HttpClient)
export class FormData{

    constructor(httpClient)
    {
        this.http = httpClient;
    }

    GetFormById(formId)
    {
        return this.http.get(`${baseUrl}/GetFormById/${formId}`)
                        .then(f => f.content);

    };
}
```

`Model`:

```
activate(params)
{
    return this.form.GetFormById(params.formId)
                    .then(f => this.form = f);
}
```

The `View`:

```
<p class="navbar-text navbar-left">
   ${form.name}
 </p>
```

The `Response`:

```
{"Id":"x","OrganisationId":"x","OrganisationDepartmentId":null,"ScheduleId":null,"DefinitionTypeId":"x","ReferenceNumber":11171,"Name":"New Form Test External Access","Description":"","IsTemplate":true,"IsActive":true,"IsSingleFormTemplate":false,"MinimumInstances":null,"MaximumInstances":null,"IsAdhocCreationEnabled":false,"HasCalculation":false,"Calculation":null,"Recalculate":true,"IsHidden":false}
```

So again I don't see the data appearing on the view and I feel I'm missing something rather simple.

**//EDITS**

So after a little digging I made a little change to my API returning a `JSON array` rather than a `JSON object` and also switched Aurelia to use `Fetch`... So now I can access the data in my data component but not my model - rather frustrating!

```
import {inject} from "aurelia-framework";
//import {HttpClient} from "aurelia-http-client";
//import 'fetch';
import {HttpClient} from 'aurelia-fetch-client';

let baseUrl = "/FormDesigner";

@inject(HttpClient)
export class FormData{

    constructor(httpClient)
    {
        httpClient.configure(config => {
            config
              .withBaseUrl('/FormDesigner')
              .withDefaults({
                  credentials: 'same-origin',
                  headers: {
                      'Accept': 'application/json',
                      'X-Requested-With': 'Fetch'
                  }
              })
              .withInterceptor({
                  request(request) {
                      console.log(`Requesting ${request.method} ${request.url}`);
                      return request;
                  },
                  response(response) {
                      console.log(`Received ${response.status} ${response.url}`);
                      return response;
                  }
              });
        });

        this.http = httpClient;
    }

    GetFormById(formId)
    {
        return this.http.fetch(`/GetFormById/${formId}`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                //Log here, to check incoming data
                console.log("From component: " + data.Name);
                //This WORKS
            });

    };
}
```

Again I've created an abstraction where as my model does not need to know about calls to the server.

```
import {inject} from "aurelia-framework";
import {FormData} from "form/formData";

@inject(FormData)
export class Form
{

    constructor(formData)
    {
        this.form = formData;

    }

    activate(params)
    {
        if(params.formId != null)
        {
            return this.form.GetFormById(params.formId)
            .then(data => 
            {
                this.form = data
                console.log(this.form.Name);
                //This does not work!!
            });
        }
        else
        {   
            //Show message that param does not exist or redirect to no form page
            console.log("No Id");
        }

    }
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you need to deserialize the JSON response into a Javascript object using `JSON.parse`.

```
GetFormById(formId)
{
  return this.http.get(`${baseUrl}/GetFormById/${formId}`)
    .then(response => JSON.parse(response.content));
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but I'm getting: "ERROR [app-router] ReferenceError: resolve is not defined(…)"

Comment: Sorry @TezWingfield , there was some copy paste confusion on my part. I have edited the answer to remove the `resolve` stuff. It should work now.

Comment: Hi, No my mistake. Developers should never copy paste - the change did not work anyhow haha. Please see my edits.